# MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator looses trigger context

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, entitlements, casemilestone

We use the MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator interface to have more dynamic milestone durations.

To prevent having to query for fields on the Case and to have to query for the milestonetype name, we use a seperate class where we store the "context" in static variables.

This context is then being filled from the afterUpdate and afterInsert trigger.

This all works fine but very rarely and (seemingly) random, the context seems to get lost.

To give an example, we have a workflow rule that will increase the priority of the Case to Medium, High or Critical on pre-determined times.
Then, for example, increase to medium would work, increase to high would fail and increase to Critical works again. 
While in other cases, no issues...
Then another day, out of the blue, increase to Critical might fail...

I am wondering if this could have something to do with where the MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator fits in the order of execution chain but I don't seem to find proper information on that. Anyone knows?
(what I would fail to understand then though is why it only fails so rarely and randomly..)

Comment: Do you clear these static variables when a Case clears and what's the maximum number of cases that your class can hold (& how are they stored)? How are the static variables mapped? Is status a factor? If so, what are the size limits on each status? Without knowing more about your class or seeing the code, it's impossible to answer. That said, it sounds like you may occasionally be exceeding the limits of what it can hold or keep track of.